# what's meaning ${} in shell?

Tags: shell

everyone, i have a problem in bash programming, that is I don't know what's mean in bash 
script:

```
${parameter:-word}
${parameter:=word}
${parameter:?word}
${parameter:+word}
${parameter:offset}
${parameter:offset:length}
${!prefix*}
${#parameter}
${parameter#word}
${parameter##word}
${parameter%word}
${parameter%%word}
${parameter/pattern/string}
${parameter//pattern/string}
```

this usage, thank you for answer me .

Comment: Bash parameter expansion is explained [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). However, your question is overly broad. Please ask a more specific question with your actual problem. Also, Stackoverflow already has a couple of Q/A for issues with shell parameter expansion in bash, so you might then check them first.

Comment: [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just open up a terminal window and enter `man bash`, you'll be able to find all of these under `Parameter Expansion`.

In fact, since these are *exactly* the form in which the man page has them (using `parameter` and `word`) and in the same order you have them, I'm surprised you don't know this already.

One example is `${parameter:-word}` which states:

> Use Default Values. If `parameter` is unset or null, the expansion of `word` is substituted. Otherwise, the value of `parameter` is substituted.

So, for that case, `${xyzzy:-plugh}` will give you the value of `${xyzzy}` if it's set, otherwise you'll get the literal `"plugh"`.

I won't go through them all, the `bash` man page explains in full detail. "Teach a man to fish ..." and all that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

**Parameter Expansion**

The format for parameter expansion is as follows:

```
${expression}
```

where expression consists of all characters until the matching '}'. Any '}' escaped by a backslash or within a quoted string, and characters in embedded arithmetic expansions, command substitutions, and variable expansions, shall not be examined in determining the matching '}'.

The simplest form for parameter expansion is:

```
${parameter}
```

For Details see:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html